# How to know if item is in the center with UPCarouselFlowLayout

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm searching a way to make appear some information when the item is in the center, and make it's disappear when it's not.

Is it possible with [UPCarouselFlowLayout](https://github.com/ink-spot/UPCarouselFlowLayout)?
Or Do you have any idea where I can make a callback to get the state of an item?

What I get for Now:
[image: Expected result]

Expected result:
[image: What I get for Now]

Thanks for any idea ;-)
regards,

Comment: Please are you using it with swift 4?

Comment: I used swift 3, but I think get no change for swift 4